# Lowering the Schwinger limit with superconductors while considering the Unruh effect?

Tags: superconductivity, pair-production, unruh-effect

Unruh Effect is often left out in calculations regarding the Schwinger limit.

I've been looking at different mechanisms for more easily attaining the Schwinger limit. So far, the only thing I have come across for **lowering** the limit is [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.08323) which describes how superconductors may be used to lower the limit from $10^{18}$ V/cm$^2$ down to $10^8$ V/cm$^2$. However, this paper doesn't address the Unruh effect at all, so not sure if taking it into account would raise or lower the limit. I would imagine taking the Unruh into account would raise the limit since superconductors don't like hotter temps, might collapse the condensate state sooner.

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.02477) details the Unruh temperature one would expect from a 1 MeV electron at $0.94 c$ colliding with 800nm, $2 \times 10^{20}$ W/cm$^2$ laser corresponding to an acceleration of $2 \times 10^{23}$ N/m/s$^2$, the Unruh temperature would be 1000K. Doesn't address anything about Schwinger pair production limits going up or down.

What I'm wondering is, would the Unruh temperature do anything to change the Schwinger limit for pair production ($10^{18}$ V/cm$^2$) either in vacuum or in a medium?

Edit: Also, it appears as though there may be an 'Anti-Unruh' effect at relativistic velocities, whereby the Unruh temp actually goes **down**. [Here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269316300727).

Would also love it if anyone had any other mechanisms (even purely hypothetical) for lowering the Schwinger limit.